# Issue with renaming a directory in git to lowercase while ignoreLowercase=True

Tags: git

When I type `git status`, I see:

```
# On branch master
# Changes not staged for commit:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#
#   modified:   DIR/a
#
```

However, in my working directory I see that this file is actually called `dir/a` (note the lowercase `dir` instead of `DIR`).

**Question:** I want to add this modified `a` file to the staging area and commit, but I want it to be as it is in my working directory (which shows `dir/a`) - *as opposed to the way git is seeing it as `DIR/a`*. How can I do this?

**Important Note:**

Unfortunately, I can't simply `git mv DIR/a dir/a` because `DIR/a` doesn't actually exist in the working tree.

Currently my `.git/config` file shows `ingorecase = true`, so I know that I have to set that equal to false. However, after doing nothing but changing this flag, a `git status` of this now reveals:

```
# On branch master
# Changes not staged for commit:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#
#   modified:   DIR/a
#
 # Untracked files:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
#
#   dir/
```

I expected this since git only tracks content, and switching ignorecase would make git think a new file was added. Unfortunately, git now thinks that I have two files that are modified, when in fact I only have one. I want `git status` to simply show `dir/a` (as it is in my working directory) instead of `DIR/a`, with the same diffs of `a` I had just recently made.

**Additional Note**

If you are curious as to how such a precarious situation arose in the first place, I have managed to replicate the silly mistakes I had made when originally renaming the case of my directory from `DIR` to `dir`. If you think this would help in getting to a solution for this problem, I would be happy to make an edit that would reveal how I mistakenly made git so confused. (it involves me accidentally hitting `mv` instead of `git mv`, and being unaware of the `ignorecase` flag and leaving it as `ignorecase=true`).

Answer (score 123, accepted):

Example: if you are lower-casing Mydir

```
git mv src/Mydir src/mydirs

git mv src/mydirs src/mydir

git commit -m "Rename folder Mydir to mydir"
```

Comment: I recalled swipe two numbers using third third variable `C` program ;)

Comment: Very important to leave the trailing `\` off the folder names. If you let Windows complete them for you and a `\` is added it won't work.

Answer (score 29):

You can also change this **case-sensitivity** in the Git configuration by executing the below command on the terminal:

```
git config core.ignorecase false
```

Comment: this won't help if you're connected to any remote cloud platform, because it will only change your setting, and eventually lead to future problems when you push to the cloud, or even move the project to a different computer/platform

Answer (score 21):

I've found a workaround. I'm not sure if there's a more elegant solution, but I have tested this and it does work.
Because git continues to think that two files exist when only one does, I had to actually just copy the directory entirely, remove what git is tracking as a file, and then mv the copied directory back to the original.

(1) commit any files in `dir` that need to be commited.

(2) `cp -r dir tempDir`

(3) `git add tempDir/`

(4) `git rm -r dir Dir`

(5) `git commit -m "Temporary rename of dir to tempDir"`

(6) `git mv tempDir mms`

(7) `git commit -m "Full rename from DIR to dir complete"`

Comment: I guess you meant.  
`(6) git mv tempDir dir` ?

Answer (score 3):

You can remove the directory from cache and readd it:

```
git rm -r --cache DIR
mv DIR dir
git add dir
```