# Local vs. Repo project.xcworkspace inconsistency

Tags: ios, xcode, git, bitrise

I am attempting to add a new iOS app into bitrise, but during the validation process I am getting the error: `contents.xcworkspacedata does not exist at: PROJECT.xcworkspace/contents.xcworkspacedata`

When I look in my repo and my local folder, I notice a couple of things:

1. The repo contains both a `PROJECT.xcworkspace` and a `project.xcworkspace`, but my local folder only contains a `PROJECT.xcworkspace`
2. Even more strange, is that in the repo, the lowercased workspace
   folder contains the `contents.xcworkspacedata` file and the uppercased workspace folder contains the `xcshareddata` folder (neither contain xcuserdata as that is ignored)
3. My local `PROJECT.xcworkspace` contains all that is expected (i.e. `contents.xcworkspacedata`, `xcshareddata/`, and `xcuserdata/`)

Bitrise validation is failing because it is looking for the file in `PROJECT.xcworkspace` in the repo, not `project.xcworkspace` where that file is actually located.

The name of the workspace has always been capitalized from the initialization of the project, so I don't understand why there would be a lowercased version in the repo.

Is this some random bug that occurred, or what is a good way to resolve this issue?

Comment: Something like this (capitalization issue) can frequently happen in git if you change the capitalization of the file. Did you check what happens if you do a new, clean git clone into a new directory? Is the workspace file there upper or lowercase? See also e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13201906/issue-with-renaming-a-directory-in-git-to-lowercase-while-ignorelowercase-true

If these wouldn't help we might need more info/the logs - I'd suggest you to send those to our support who can check it & help you there.

Comment: @ViktorBenei It was some weird bug with git... I just deleted the capitalized .xcworkspace folder directly in the git repo, and then re-pushed and everything was fine... Must have just been a git bug.

Comment: Indeed I think you were "tricked" by the git case insensitivity behaviour - https://discuss.bitrise.io/t/react-native-unable-to-resolve-module/2359/2?u=viktorbenei