# ASP.NET/C#: "The type or namespace name could not be found" error - when the referenced class is clearly there

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio-2012, namespaces

I need to state first I'm new to both programming and Stack Overflow - trying to follow the guidelines as good as I can, so please bear with me if I'm doing anything wrong or asking stupid or inadequate questions, I'm trying my best to do everything right.

Reason I'm posting here is I've got stuck with an error within my internship project (ASP.NET/C# with Visual Studio 2012) lately, which appeared when trying and compile all of a sudden, without any major changes being taken before. Which is absolutely confusing to me, as everything has been working fine for weeks before.

In the Page_Load method of my Start.aspx.cs class, I'm calling a method named OrtAuslesen.cs (set to public, so that shouldn't be an issue), both are located right in the root folder of my application:

```
namespace myProject
{
   public partial class Start : System.Web.UI.Page
   {
       protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {
          (...)
          OrtAuslesen oa = new OrtAuslesen();
          (...)
       }
    }
}
```

As said, this used to work fine, however, I'm getting the following error now:

> Error 3   The type or namespace name 'OrtAuslesen' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)   D:\myProject\myProject\Start.aspx.cs

Throughout the last days, I've tried as many different approaches as I could find - clean&rebuild, restart, change of .NET framework, all possible changes of Build Action and copy behaviour of my web.config as well as the affected classes, without any success however. Some solutions suggested to implement a missing namespace - yet, as both classes are within the same project folder, there should not be any need for a using directive, is that right? In case not, I also tried implementing a using directive for the very project both classes are located within, but without success.

Any further ideas what I could do to get my project running again would be highly appreciated - if there's anything else you need to know that I didnt' think of, please let me know.

Comment: What is the namespace of "OrtAuslesen.cs" class?

Comment: As commented on Sachin Gaikwad's answer - the namespaces of Start.aspx.cs and OrtAuslesen.cs are both the same, in my example myProject (as is the name of the solution itself) - am I missing out on anything or should that be correct?

Comment: that should be enough. IT may sound stupid, but just to verify add another class in the project, and try creating the object for that new class.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, doesn't sound as stupid as I feel for not having thought of this before. However, things are getting even weirder - I've added a new class Testclass.cs and copied the whole code of OrtAuslesen.cs in there. Accessing Testclass.cs in Visual Studio works just fine (which OrtAuslesen.cs doesn't), with full intellisense support and such. Though, after compiling, I'm getting the same error again (in the browser window only):

Compiler Error Message: CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Testclass' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: In Browser window? what about visual studio error list? Also go the bin folder of the project delete all compiled dlls, clean and rebuild.

Comment: Using the newly built class, I only get the error within the browser window, not in the error list of VS anymore. Just tried your approach (delete dlls, clean&rebuild), no changes unfortunately - massive thanks for your efforts so far though!

Comment: Close all your browsers. If visual studio shows build succeeded with not error, click on run button. It should open a new browser. Lets see if it works there

Comment: Brings no changes as well, unfortunately.

Comment: Try these. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15395042/weird-c-sharp-type-or-namespace-name-could-not-be-found-builds-successfully

Comment: Thanks again - however, that one is a different problem, as his program builds successfully, but mine not. Already tried changing the target framework before which didn't help, neither did changing the platform target, neither x86, x64 nor "Any CPU" caused any changes. Other answers on that topic won't help either as I only have one project within my solution.

Comment: Is this an ASP.NET Web Site,  or a Web Application Project?  What command did you use to create it?

Comment: I'm not really sure about the difference? I've chosen an ASP.NET Empty Web Application template when creating my project, the single pages have been added using the Web Form template (.aspx).