# The type or namespace name could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a asp.net website i made a database service library made a dll file for that and imported that in website.it works fine in local but when i uploaded it on host i met an error
could not fine assembly even though file is in bin folder.

```
Line 5:  using System.Web.UI;
Line 6:  using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
Line 7:  using my.LinqClasses;
Line 8:  
Line 9:  public partial class Webcontrols_Sidemenu : System.Web.UI.UserControl
```

my.LinqClasses is showing error
CS0246: The type or namespace name 'my' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: What type are you getting this error for?  It won't be possible to answer this without at least knowing what namespace / type isn't available

Comment: how you uploaded the file? there may be permission problems...

Comment: What is the exact error message: Unable to find .... .dll? Please fill the blanks

Comment: CS0246: The type or namespace name 'my' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Does `my.LinqClasses` actually exists? If it does, is it declared in the same assembly? If it is not, is there a reference to the assembly it is declared in?

Comment: With some third-party items used locally, I've had to grant read/execute permissions on the DLLs used to the app pool's service account for the web site, but those were typically unmanaged DLLs.  Still, it's something to try.

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3304741/vs2010-getting-type-or-namespace-name-could-not-be-found-but-everything-seem

Comment: if that doesn't solve it, check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4764978/the-type-or-namespace-name-could-not-be-found. it worked for me

Answer (score 2):

Just right click on the error and select the "resolve using" (if present). This will add the missing assembly directive in your webform. If the option is not available the attach the correct assembly manually. Hope this help.