# Import LibGaze dll file in Unity3D

Tags: c#, dll, unity-game-engine, mono

I want to import the dll file of LibGaze in Unity.

I put the dll in the "Assets/Plugins" folder. I managed to add that dll as reference in mono editor, the namespace and classes seem to be recognized by mono editor without problem (when I type class names in the dll, they are in the list of auto-completion).

But when I go back to unity main window, it says: "error CS0246: The type or namespace name `libGaze' could not be found. Are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?" When I double click this error message, it points me to the using statement of LibGaze library in the script.

Comment: You need Unity Pro to use (import) Dll's, are you using Unity Free or Unity Pro?

Comment: Yes, i'm using the pro version of Unity.

Comment: Don't use unity tag for questions related to Unity3d game engine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found this question which seems to explain my problem : [Getting "type or namespace name could not be found" but everything seems ok?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3304741/vs2010-getting-type-or-namespace-name-could-not-be-found-but-everything-seem)

Since unity only support .Net 2.0 and the dll file is compiled with a higher version of .Net, unity cant correctly import it.

Tested with the new unity5, mono editor still only supports .Net 2.0