# how to call a method from class in seperate project

Tags: c#, unit-testing

I have a class library project and have added to that another project which is a unit test project. In the class library project I have the following code:

```
public class NumberManipulator
{
    public int FindMax(int num1, int num2)
    {
        int result;
        if (num1 > num2)
            result = num1;
        else
            result = num2;
        return result;
    }
}
```

A simple bit of code to return the highest number out of two inputs. In my unit test project I am trying to call the FindMax method using the following:

```
NumberManipulator test = new NumberManipulator();
```

but the class is not recognised and giving the following message "The type or namespace name 'NumberManipulator' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

I have referenced the class project in the unit test project, not sure why I'm not able to call that class though.

Comment: if you have referenced the CORRECT project, then there is no reason on why it will not pick up the class...

Comment: Have you added the correct `using SomeNameSpace;` at the top of your unit test class file?

Comment: So, having read the error are you missing a `using` statement or an assembly reference?

Comment: you can read about [Getting “type or namespace name could not be found”](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3304899/3796048)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you will have to add

```
using nameSpace (where namespace would be namespace of your class library project.)
```

or other way would be:

```
<namespaceName>.NumberManipulator test = new <namespaceName>.NumberManipulator();
```