# The type or namespace name 'ADONetAppender' could not be found

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

We have a legacy ASP.NET application which was in 1.1 now I imported it to VS2010 which converted the project to .net 2.0

After importing the solution am seeing errors compiling below class

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Text;
using log4net;
using log4net.Appender;
using log4net.Config;
using log4net.Repository.Hierarchy;
[assembly: DOMConfigurator(Watch=true)]

namespace DC.Utilities
{
    public class Logger
    {
       private static ADONetAppender _adoNetAppender        = null;
      //other functions
     } 
}
```

When I try compiling the solution am seeing the below error

```
error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'ADONetAppender' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

Can someone help me with this issue?

Comment: Are the references for log4net in the solution correctly? Delete and re-add them? You may also be able to right click on `ADONetAppender` and see if there's the `Resolve` option.

Comment: I did delete and re-added the log4net.dll but still the compilation error showing up

Comment: is the log4net version compatible with .NET 2.0? you might need a newer one

Comment: This thread might also have some extra information: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3304741/getting-type-or-namespace-name-could-not-be-found-but-everything-seems-ok

Answer (score 1):

log4net reference should be missing while opening .net 1.1 solotion in VS2010 (converting to .net 2.0). Verify the reference as shown below by expanding the `References` of your project, either delete and add the reference of log4net once again or copy log4net.dll to the appropriate location and refresh the project in VS2010.

[image]