# Namespaces not recognized though they exist in VS 2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, namespaces

In the C# VS2010 Solution I'm working in, there is a namespace called: `EBI.Core.Base.Constant.EBISystem`

That namespace's DLL is referenced as a Project (i.e. a project native to the solution,) in a different project in the same solution.

VS shows error saying that: The type of namespace **Base** does not exist. This is true, it does not exist because the actual name is the full namespace name above.

When I remove the project reference and add it back in, the error goes away and the full namespace name is recognized, but as soon as I build, the error comes back. Same thing happens if I close the solution and re-open it, no error, until I build.

This error seems to be happening only on my dev machine and no one else's with the same exact solution.

I looked at my GAC and there's no stray or missing dll there. I have closed and restarted the solution, I have restarted my machine to no avail. Also checked project build dependencies and they are correct. Unloaded and released the project, still the same thing.

Both the project being worked on and the referenced project are .Net 3.5.

Wondering if anyone has any suggestions. I've tried everything here: [Getting "type or namespace name could not be found" but everything seems ok?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3304741/getting-type-or-namespace-name-could-not-be-found-but-everything-seems-ok)

Comment: Did you try cleaning the solution? I find this often resolves issues like this. ([MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5tdasz7h(v=vs.100).aspx))

Comment: Yes, I did that. No go.

Answer (score 0):

Use the same target framework version for your project and the library "EBI.Core.Base.Constant.EBISystem"

Comment: Ok, this append for me only one time but check the .net framework 4 gac directory, if you find your library with the same version try to remove it and recompile

Comment: Aha! The .net 4 Gac (C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL), had one dll that the projects reference, I removed it and the error went away! Up to now I'd only been checking the standard GAC since my projects were 3.5.