# Missing an assembly reference or directive

Tags: c#, winforms, csv

```
 private void btn_create_Click(object sender,EventArgs e)


{
string s1, s2, s3, s4, s5, s6;
s1= txtlbl1.Text;
s2= txtlbl2.Text;
s3= txtlbl3.Text;
s4= txtlbl4.Text;
s5= txtlbl5.Text;
s6= txtlbl6.Text;



using(StreamWriter sw= new StreamWriter(“full_path_name.txt”, true));


{
sw.Writeline(string.Format(“[0]#[1]#[2]#[3]#[4]#[5]”, new object[]     {s1,s2,s3,s4,s5,s6}));
}
```

Hello I’m quite new to c# and I’m trying to write to a text file using # as a delimiter and I’m getting a few error your help would be appreciated! A picture of the errors will be attached [errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vHDqc.jpg)

Comment: Sounds like you're missing a using directive of `using System.IO;` at the top of the file. In future, please include errors as *text* within the question rather than as screenshots or photos. Error messages are textual, so including them as text makes them much easier to read.

Comment: In addition to what @JonSkeet mentioned, I'm not sure if this was a copy paste error, but the quotation marks `“` and `”` may be causing issues depending on the IDE, as it may consider these as not valid string markers.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Type/ NameSpace could not be found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38467189/type-namespace-could-not-be-found)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So first off, there's a couple of things to start with that would make it easier for people to help you out.

***Make sure your code is formatted correctly.***

After your using statement, you have a semicolon(;) which is breaking the semantics of the code so you should remove that.
Also double check your curly baces{}, you're missing one at the end.

***Down to the question at hand***

We can't see your using statements at the top of the .cs file which are the dependencies that your current .cs file uses which is most likely where the problem is originating from. Please add this to the very top of your .cs file as suggested by another user on your question's comments.

```
using System.IO;
```