# Intellisense in DNN Christoc Module Development template not working for registered controls

Tags: asp.net, module, dotnetnuke, intellisense, dotnetnuke-7

I have created a module using the Christoc Module Development templates for Visual Studio 2015 on a local install of DNN 7.4.1. In my module I am using Telerik controls as well as DNN controls including dnn:DnnJsInclude, dnn:TextEditor, telerik:RadGrid and more.

I previously installed the module on a website by registering it as a control through the 'Create Module' wizard but decided to package it as a module using the template so that I could have it in source control.

I installed a blank module using the template and then copied over the markup and code behind for my module.

The issues I am having with the template are that intellisense no longer recognises any of the controls that I have had to register and I am therefore unable to see any properties for these controls. This is making development extremely difficult, however the module does build. I am registering the controls like this:

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="dnn" Assembly="DotNetNuke.Web" Namespace="DotNetNuke.Web.UI.WebControls" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="dnn" Namespace="DotNetNuke.Web.Client.ClientResourceManagement" Assembly="DotNetNuke.Web.Client" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="dnn" TagName="TextEditor" Src="~/controls/TextEditor.ascx" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="telerik" Namespace="Telerik.Web.UI" Assembly="Telerik.Web.UI" %>
```

In addition to this, my code behind file cannot recognise the type of control when I have used the TextEditor control so I am having to cast it to get it to compile. Furthermore, when I try to use embedded code blocks, I am getting the error that the mothod does not exist in the current context, despite the fact that the module is able to build.

I am not having this issue with another module I created using Syncfusion controls, possibly as the related assemblies are registered in the GAC though I'm not sure if this is the reason why.

I know there are a few different issue detailed here but if anyone could shed any light on how to fix them I would be very grateful.

Comment: Maybe this will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3304741/getting-type-or-namespace-name-could-not-be-found-but-everything-seems-ok.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found some solutions for my issues.

In order to get Intellisense to register the Telerik controls and DNN controls in the DNN assemblies, I had to create a bin folder within the module and add the following dll's:

- DotNetNuke.dll
- DotNetNuke.Web.dll
- DotNetNuke.WebControls.dll
- Telerik.Web.UI.dll

I then rebuilt the module and restarted Visual Studio and Intellisense was working.

I am still however having issues with the registered controls, i.e. TextEditor, URLControl and am having to manually register them in the codebehind like so:

```
protected DotNetNuke.UI.UserControls.UrlControl urlControl;
```

Answer (score 0):

Couple of issues.

Regarding Intellisense, are you using the DNNDEV.ME url that the templates are setup to use? I would start there to make sure that things are going to work 100% If you are using a different URL for your environment, right click on the project, choose properties and configure the proper URL on the web tab. Sometimes that can cause intellisense issues.

Regarding the code behind, you likely need to right click on the ASCX file and "convert to web app" or something similar, that should generate the .designer files that you are likely missing.

Comment: Hi Chris, I made a quick edit as I noticed I had got wrote Visual Studio 2012 instead of 2015 in case that makes a difference, also DNN 7.4.1 not 7.4.2. Yes I am using the DNNDEV.ME url. I converted the .csproj file to a web application as I couldn't do it for the ascx file but that had no effect. I also noticed I don't have intellisense issues when I open up the website and navigate to the desktopmodules folder, but I do when I just open up the module project.