# The type or namespace name '“Namespace”' could not be found in the global namespace (are you missing an assembly reference?)

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio

I am trying to build a solution and getting the following error:

> Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error   CS0400  The type or namespace name 'CMSInstall_Controls_WizardSteps_CollationDialog' could not be found in the global namespace (are you missing an assembly reference?)    Fortius.CMS D:\Kentico10Migration\GithubMegha\Fortius.CMS\CMS\CMSInstall\install.aspx.designer.cs   390 Active
>
> Designer file is not recognising
>
> "CMSInstall_Controls_WizardSteps_CollationDialog"
>
> /// 
>       /// ucCollationDialog control.
>       /// 
>       /// 
>       /// Auto-generated field.
>       /// To modify move field declaration from designer file to code-behind file.
>       /// 
>       protected global::CMSInstall_Controls_WizardSteps_CollationDialog ucCollationDialog;

But another solution file have same install.aspx install.aspx.cs install.aspx.desginer.cs files present but no errors while build it.

Comment: Do the projects have same references....

Comment: There is probably a nuget package you have installed into the one project but not into the other.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting "type or namespace name could not be found" but everything seems ok?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3304741/getting-type-or-namespace-name-could-not-be-found-but-everything-seems-ok)

Answer (score -1):

I fixed the issue:

Issue was the class which is provided in designer file was present in a file which was excluded in the solution. I have included all files and error went away!

Yipieee!!