# intellisense error but no build error

Tags: visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-2017, intellisense

My .net solution builds fine but I keep getting intellisense errors "the type or namespace name could not be found ( are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)".

I tried suspending and restarting resharper, clear resharper cache, cleaning and rebuilding the solution, restarting my machine, closing and opening visual studio and deleting the suo and obj files by running git clean and going to the directory and verifying that those binaries were deleted.
Finally I moved from visual studio 2015 to 2017 but I am still getting the same intellisense error and red squiggly lines throughout my solution

Comment: Would help to say what the errors are. If you aren't getting compiler errors, they may be warnings. If that's the case, the code may compile fine, but you may run into a RuntimeException later.

Comment: included the actual error message

Comment: @JayJayJay, please check this similar issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3304741/getting-type-or-namespace-name-could-not-be-found-but-everything-seems-ok and if you have some projects under this solution, make sure they are target to the same .NET Framework version, right click the project name > Properties > Application to confirm it. Remove and re-add the references under the project or re-install the nuget packages.