# VS2017 - Solution builds correctly with false errors (corrupted .vs folder?)

Tags: visual-studio, intellisense

I'm using VS 2017 Community and I'm working on a solution that has 2 custom projects, we'll call them MainApp and DependencyLibrary. There is a project reference from MainApp to DependencyLibrary.

Every once in a while, the IDE just starts to report errors as if the reference to DependencyLibrary is missing (and IntelliSense stops working for that library, too).

[image]

Of course, I've triple-checked and validated that the reference is still there, and the solution will even build PERFECTLY, even with the reported errors, so the compiler knows there's no problem.

If I close out of Visual Studio completely and re-enter the solution, it's still in the same state (reports errors and Intellisense is broken, but builds perfectly).

If I close out of Visual Studio and remove the .vs folder for the solution, it seems to fix the problem, but then I lose all of my local/personal settings (open files, etc...). So there IS a workaround, but it's annoying and I'm wondering if there's any known issue that I'm accidentally doing that leads to this situation.

Note that I've checked these other SO posts:

[intellisense error but no build error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45194381/intellisense-error-but-no-build-error)

[Getting "type or namespace name could not be found" but everything seems ok?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3304741/getting-type-or-namespace-name-could-not-be-found-but-everything-seems-ok)

The first post is unanswered and just refers to the second post, but per the second post, I've validated that both projects are targeting the exact same .NET framework versions and none of the other comments or answers in that second post seem to be relevant to my solution.

Comment: It is a random issue? If right click the solution name and Clean solution, it works or not?

Comment: It seems random, yes. I will try the clean solution the next time. Last time it happened, I needed to fully remove the reference and re-add it. Removing the .vs folder didn't fully fix it.

Answer (score 0):

For me this was due to a nuget package, specifically due to Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatfom I had different versions of the same package in different projects, once I referenced the same version in all projects the errors were solved.