# Unity external references (dll) issue

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, dll

I'm having an issue with external assemblies in Unity and it just baffles me on how to fix them. So, I needed a package called "OpenWeatherMap.NET", so I imported it into my Unity project through Visual Studio (NuGet). Then I got an error about the missing namespace, so I copied all the dlls to a folder in Unity. Now I'm getting

> "an assembly with the same identity has already been imported.
>   Consider removing one of the references."

. So I do that, and then I get errors about [missing packages.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cevi7.png) But if I restore the deleted file, I get the "same identity" error again.
The imported assemblies are: **"Microsoft.Bcl.1.1.10"**, **"Microsoft.Bcl.Async.1.0.168"**, **"Microsoft.Bcl.Build.1.0.21"**, **"Microsoft.Net.Http.2.2.29"** and **"OpenWeatherMap.dll"**.
They were all previously imported through NuGet and are present in the "packages" folder of the project.

[image of the folder of one of the assemblies](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ERLkj.png)

Comment: So you are using Visual Studio for Mac?

Comment: @LexLi Visual Studio 2017 for Windows (Windows 10)

Comment: Then you are also using the latest Unity (experimental support of .NET 4)?

Comment: @LexLi Unity 2017.1f1 with experimental .NET 4.6

Comment: I think this is the answer you are looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3304741/getting-type-or-namespace-name-could-not-be-found-but-everything-seems-ok