# Not found reference Rotativa

Tags: c#, .net, razor, model-view-controller, rotativa

I want to used the `Rotativa lib` but not found it reference when it installed by `Nuget`.
I have the App_browser and Rotativa folders , but not reference to Rotativa
Why?

add the reference to Rotativa.ddl but do not compile. I have this **error**

> The type or namespace name 'Rotativa' could not be found (are you
>   missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Sorry for my English.
Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting "type or namespace name could not be found" but everything seems ok?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3304741/getting-type-or-namespace-name-could-not-be-found-but-everything-seems-ok)

Comment: has this been fixed

Answer (score 4):

Try to use pre-release version:

https://github.com/webgio/Rotativa/issues/177

In Nuget, mark checkbox "Include prerelises' near seach textbox.