# Cannot call a Windows form from main

Tags: c#, winforms, constructor

I am trying to call the windows form (SortpBoundaryImages) from my main but it comes back with "The type or namespace name 'SortpBoundaryImages' could not be found (are you missing an directive or assembly reference)?

```
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace DataCollection
{
public class Layers
{
    [CommandMethod("CivilData")]

    public static void Main()
    {

        Form sortP = new SortpBoundarImages();
}}}
```

This is my form code in a separate .cs file.

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace DataCollection.Classes
{
public partial class SortpBoundaryImages : Form
{
    public SortpBoundaryImages()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void pictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
}
```

I am not sure what I should be looking at, I have revised constructors and inheritance tutorials that I watched the other day but I am not sure if that is even the problem.

Comment: possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3304741/getting-type-or-namespace-name-could-not-be-found-but-everything-seems-ok

Comment: _are you missing an directive or assembly reference_ - ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
using System.Windows.Forms;

using DataCollection.Classes;                  // <<<<<<<<<<<<<< Add this line

namespace DataCollection
{
public class Layers
{
    [CommandMethod("CivilData")]

    public static void Main()
    {

        Form sortP = new SortpBoundarImages();
}}}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace DataCollection
{
public class Layers
{
    [CommandMethod("CivilData")]

    public static void Main()
    {

        Form sortP = new Classes.SortpBoundarImages();
}}}
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked as well. I didn't relies I had to add in .classes. The autogenerated form just had it in there