# Why can't Visual Studio find my assemblies?

Tags: macos, visual-studio, macos-mojave, visual-studio-mac

I'm new to Visual Studio, but not to programming. I tried to open a project which someone else sent me, and there are lots of errors (they are all the same). Please see the image below:

[image]

When I tried to check the runtimes installed, I see this:

[image]

I know that Newtonsoft.Json is installed, because I can see it in the packages folder.

So far I have looked at:
[Getting "type or namespace name could not be found" but everything seems ok?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3304741/getting-type-or-namespace-name-could-not-be-found-but-everything-seems-ok)

But I can't figure out how to fix the problem, as I'm using VS after several years. What should I do ?

I am using Visual Studio for Mac Community edition, version 8.2.3 (build 16)

EDIT: More Information from about Visual Studio:

> === Visual Studio Community 2019 for Mac ===
>
> Version 8.2.3 (build 16) Installation UUID:
>   024bbaaf-47dd-4755-982d-29b842a90ef4  GTK+ 2.24.23 (Raleigh theme)
>     Xamarin.Mac 5.14.0.85 (d16-2-fix-mac-updates / 86973979)
>
> Package version: 600000319
>
> === Mono Framework MDK ===
>
> Runtime:  Mono 6.0.0.319 (2019-02/52203786470) (64-bit)   Package
>   version: 600000319
>
> === NuGet ===
>
> Version: 5.1.0.6013
>
> === .NET Core ===
>
> Runtime: /usr/local/share/dotnet/dotnet Runtime Versions:
>     2.1.12
>     2.1.2 SDK: /usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/2.1.701/Sdks SDK Versions:
>     2.1.701
>     2.1.302 MSBuild SDKs: /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/6.0.0/lib/mono/msbuild/Current/bin/Sdks
>
> === Xamarin.Profiler ===
>
> Version: 1.6.11 Location: /Applications/Xamarin
>   Profiler.app/Contents/MacOS/Xamarin Profiler
>
> === Updater ===
>
> Version: 11
>
> === Xamarin.Android ===
>
> Version: 9.4.1.0 (Visual Studio Community) Commit:
>   xamarin-android/d16-2/ebd65c9 Android SDK:
>   /Users/morgoth/Library/Android/sdk    Supported Android versions:
>         4.4 (API level 19)
>         5.0 (API level 21)
>         5.1 (API level 22)
>         6.0 (API level 23)
>         7.0 (API level 24)
>         7.1 (API level 25)
>         8.0 (API level 26)
>         8.1 (API level 27)
>
> SDK Tools Version: 26.1.1 SDK Platform Tools Version: 29.0.1 SDK Build
>   Tools Version: 28.0.3
>
> Build Information:  Mono: mono/mono/2019-02@e6f5369c2d2 Java.Interop:
>   xamarin/java.interop/d16-2@d64ada5 LibZipSharp:
>   grendello/LibZipSharp/d16-2@caa0c74 LibZip:
>   nih-at/libzip/rel-1-5-1@b95cf3f ProGuard:
>   xamarin/proguard/master@905836d SQLite: xamarin/sqlite/3.27.1@8212a2d
>   Xamarin.Android Tools: xamarin/xamarin-android-tools/d16-2@6f6c969
>
> === Microsoft Mobile OpenJDK ===
>
> Java SDK:
>   /Users/morgoth/Library/Developer/Xamarin/jdk/microsoft_dist_openjdk_1.8.0.25
>   1.8.0-25 Android Designer EPL code available here: https://github.com/xamarin/AndroidDesigner.EPL
>
> === Android Device Manager ===
>
> Version: 1.2.0.60 Hash: 686c817 Branch: remotes/origin/d16-2 Build
>   date: 2019-08-07 15:49:58 UTC
>
> === Apple Developer Tools ===
>
> Xcode 10.3 (14492.2) Build 10G8
>
> === Xamarin.Mac ===
>
> Version: 5.14.0.114 (Visual Studio Community) Hash: c6691164 Branch:
>   d16-2 Build date: 2019-07-29 15:54:06-0400
>
> === Xamarin.iOS ===
>
> Version: 12.14.0.114 (Visual Studio Community) Hash: c6691164 Branch:
>   d16-2 Build date: 2019-07-29 15:54:05-0400
>
> === Xamarin Designer ===
>
> Version: 16.2.0.379 Hash: 3f0652957 Branch: remotes/origin/d16-2 Build
>   date: 2019-08-01 17:32:50 UTC
>
> === Xamarin Inspector ===
>
> Version: 1.4.3 Hash: db27525 Branch: 1.4-release Build date: Mon, 09
>   Jul 2018 21:20:18 GMT Client compatibility: 1
>
> === Build Information ===
>
> Release ID: 802030016 Git revision:
>   f438e4b3ac81dbc614da2f2d9ac3c70ea2e5c350 Build date: 2019-08-09
>   09:07:01+00 Build branch: release-8.2 Xamarin extensions:
>   67f026710e882e318fb0c90077b429be3dc0e688
>
> === Operating System ===
>
> Mac OS X 10.14.5 Darwin 18.6.0 Darwin Kernel Version 18.6.0
>       Thu Apr 25 23:16:27 PDT 2019
>       root:xnu-4903.261.4~2/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64

Comment: Not sure how it work on VS for Mac but there should be an option to change the target framework from ".Net Framework 4 Client Profile" to ".Net Framework 4" i.e. the full framework, assuming you have it installed.

Comment: @phuzi I've been wondering the same. No idea where to find the option.

Answer (score 0):

I opened the project in VS 2017 on Windows 10. I uninstalled Newtonsoft.json, and reinstalled it. Everything seems to work (on Windows). I guess VS for Mac isn't pulling its weight.