# The type or namespace couldn't be find , how to fix it?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So im doing a unity car game and one of my script for the physics is not working and i dont know why.
there is my code :

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

[RequireComponent(typeof(InputManager))]
public class CarController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public InputManager im;
    public List<wheelCollider> steeringWheel;
    public List<wheelCollider> piloteWheel;
```

and i got the following errors : "error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'wheelCollider' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

Do you know how to fix it ?

Comment: This question already has an answer here: [Getting “type or namespace name could not be found” but everything seems ok?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3304899/6617941)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting "type or namespace name could not be found" but everything seems ok?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3304741/getting-type-or-namespace-name-could-not-be-found-but-everything-seems-ok)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo, 'wheelCollider' should be 'WheelCollider' with an uppercase 'W'.