# Unity 2019 error The type or namespace name 'NotSupportedException' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

The type or namespace name 'NotSupportedException' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
error only happens in unity when trying to compile. in visual studio does not show error messages
I tried to look for solutions but nothing worked, could someone help me solve this problem?
how to solve?

error Assets\HeroEditor4D\Common\EditorScripts\CharacterEditor.cs(141,23): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'NotSupportedException' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

```
    #else

    public override void Save(string path)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }

    public override void Load(string path)
    {
LINE ERROR        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }

    #endif
```

-

```
using Assets.HeroEditor4D.Common.CharacterScripts;
using HeroEditor.Common;
using UnityEngine;

namespace Assets.HeroEditor4D.Common.EditorScripts
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Character editor UI and behaviour.
    /// </summary>
    public class CharacterEditor : CharacterEditorBase
    {
        [Header("Other")]
        public bool UseEditorColorField = true;
        public string PrefabFolder;
        public string TestRoomSceneName;

        private static Character _temp;

        /// <summary>
        /// Called automatically on app start.
        /// </summary>
        public void Awake()
        {
            RestoreTempCharacter();
        }

        public void OnValidate()
        {
            if (Character == null)
            {
                Character = FindObjectOfType<Character4D>();
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Remove all equipment.
        /// </summary>
        public void Reset()
        {
            Character.Parts.ForEach(i => i.ResetEquipment());
            InitializeDropdowns();
        }

        #if UNITY_EDITOR

        /// <summary>
        /// Save character to prefab.
        /// </summary>
        public void Save()
        {
            PrefabFolder = UnityEditor.EditorUtility.SaveFilePanel("Save character prefab", PrefabFolder, "New character", "prefab");

            if (PrefabFolder.Length > 0)
            {
                Save("Assets" + PrefabFolder.Replace(Application.dataPath, null));
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Load character from prefab.
        /// </summary>
        public void Load()
        {
            PrefabFolder = UnityEditor.EditorUtility.OpenFilePanel("Load character prefab", PrefabFolder, "prefab");

            if (PrefabFolder.Length > 0)
            {
                Load("Assets" + PrefabFolder.Replace(Application.dataPath, null));
            }

            //FeatureTip();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Save character to json.
        /// </summary>
        public void SaveToJson()
        {
            PrefabFolder = UnityEditor.EditorUtility.SaveFilePanel("Save character to json", PrefabFolder, "New character", "json");

            if (PrefabFolder.Length > 0)
            {
                var path = "Assets" + PrefabFolder.Replace(Application.dataPath, null);
                var json = Character.ToJson();

                System.IO.File.WriteAllText(path, json);
                Debug.LogFormat("Json saved to {0}: {1}", path, json);
            }

            //FeatureTip();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Load character from json.
        /// </summary>
        public void LoadFromJson()
        {
            PrefabFolder = UnityEditor.EditorUtility.OpenFilePanel("Load character from json", PrefabFolder, "json");

            if (PrefabFolder.Length > 0)
            {
                var path = "Assets" + PrefabFolder.Replace(Application.dataPath, null);
                var json = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(path);

                Character.LoadFromJson(json);
            }

            //FeatureTip();
        }

        public override void Save(string path)
        {
            Character.transform.localScale = Vector3.one;

            #if UNITY_2018_3_OR_NEWER

            UnityEditor.PrefabUtility.SaveAsPrefabAsset(Character.gameObject, path);

            #else

            UnityEditor.PrefabUtility.CreatePrefab(path, Character.gameObject);

            #endif

            Debug.LogFormat("Prefab saved as {0}", path);
        }

        public override void Load(string path)
        {
            var character = UnityEditor.AssetDatabase.LoadAssetAtPath<Character4D>(path);

            //Character.GetComponent<Character>().Firearm.Params = character.Firearm.Params; // TODO: Workaround
            Load(character);
            //FindObjectOfType<CharacterBodySculptor>().OnCharacterLoaded(character);
        }

        #else

        public override void Save(string path)
        {
            throw new NotSupportedException();
        }

        public override void Load(string path)
        {
            throw new NotSupportedException();
        }

        #endif

        /// <summary>
        /// Test character with demo setup.
        /// </summary>
        public void Test()
        {
            //#if UNITY_EDITOR

            //if (UnityEditor.EditorBuildSettings.scenes.All(i => !i.path.Contains(TestRoomSceneName)))
            //{
            //  UnityEditor.EditorUtility.DisplayDialog("HeroView Editor", string.Format("Please add '{0}.scene' to Build Settings!", TestRoomSceneName), "OK");
            //  return;
            //}

            //#endif

            //var controller = Character.gameObject.AddComponent<CharacterController>();

            //controller.center = new Vector3(0, 1.125f);
            //controller.height = 2.5f;
            //controller.radius = 0.75f;
            //Character.GetComponent<WeaponControls>().enabled = true;
            //Character.gameObject.AddComponent<CharacterControl>();
            //DontDestroyOnLoad(Character);
            //_temp = Character as Character;
            //SceneManager.LoadScene(TestRoomSceneName);

            //FeatureTip();
        }

        protected override void OpenPalette(GameObject palette, Color selected)
        {
            #if UNITY_EDITOR_WIN

            if (UseEditorColorField)
            {
                EditorColorField.Open(selected);
            }
            else

            #endif

            {
                Editor.SetActive(false);
                palette.SetActive(true);
            }
        }

        private void RestoreTempCharacter()
        {
            //if (_temp == null) return;

            //Character.GetComponent<Character>().Firearm.Params = _temp.Firearm.Params; // TODO: Workaround
            //Load(_temp);
            //FindObjectOfType<CharacterBodySculptor>().OnCharacterLoaded(_temp);
            //Destroy(_temp.gameObject);
            //_temp = null;
        }

        protected override void FeedbackTip()
        {
            #if UNITY_EDITOR

            var success = UnityEditor.EditorUtility.DisplayDialog("HeroView Editor", "Hi! Thank you for using my asset! I hope you enjoy making your game with it. The only thing I would ask you to do is to leave a review on the Asset Store. It would be awasome support for my asset, thanks!", "Review", "Later");

            RequestFeedbackResult(success, false);

            #endif
        }

        private void FeatureTip()
        {
            #if UNITY_EDITOR

            if (UnityEditor.EditorUtility.DisplayDialog("HeroView Editor", "This feature is available only in PRO asset version!", "Navigate", "Cancel"))
            {
                Application.OpenURL(LinkToProVersion);
            }

            #endif
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Seems it is not supported :o)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting "type or namespace name could not be found" but everything seems ok?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3304741/getting-type-or-namespace-name-could-not-be-found-but-everything-seems-ok)

Comment: @HamidYusifli This is more specific and was perfect for a Google Search for the type or namespace error related to this exception. Especially as the accepted answer was the perfect solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this line to the top of your script:

```
using System;
```