# Asp.net core Identity Models namespace name could not be found

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I added Asp.net Identity in my WebUi and in my laptop works well. But in other colleague's pc once pulled the code, it is gettings these errors. Also on another laptop I have, it is also happening the same issue.

No packages missing. Any suggestion?

[image: Namespace missing]

Comment: This problem usually represents the result of incompatible framework versions，please refer to:https://stackoverflow.com/a/3304899/12884742

Answer (score 0):

I often get this when i just cloned an existing project to my computer.
Usually it's just because nuget hasn't downloaded the packages yet. Usually it should restore all packages on build or run: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/package-restore

Comment: exactly what package are you using?