# Unity always returns namespace error for the base class (behind the colon)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

this is what unity returned after I edited the code

Assets\MainObjectSystem\Code\ThisSystem.cs(5,26): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'MainObjectSystem' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

here's the code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class ThisSystem : MainObjectSystem
{
  
}
```

This problem has stuck with me for many months, but I do not know what the error means and it would mean a lot if you helped!

Comment: Where is `MainObjectSystem`? Can you show us the definition of it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting "type or namespace name could not be found" but everything seems ok?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3304741/getting-type-or-namespace-name-could-not-be-found-but-everything-seems-ok)

Answer (score 1):

This error:

> The type or namespace name `MainObjectSystem` could not be found (are you missing a
> using directive or an assembly reference?)

Tells you that the class `MainObjectSystem` cannot be found. There should be a library or .cs file in your project that contain the code like `public class MainObjectSystem`.

Do you remember when did you develop the class `MainObjectSystem`?
This could be part of a framework you no longer reference or a code file that you accidentally deleted / moved.

Also you may hover your mouse to the word `MainObjectSystem` to see if there are any possible fixes, this issue could also just caused by not including the library by adding `using` statement.

Comment: MainObjectSystem is the folder that houses the ThisSystem.cs file

Comment: `MainObjectSystem` is not suppose to be just a folder. If `ThisSystem` is not extending a class called `MainObjectSystem`, remove `: MainObjectSystem` from your code. [Read how the syntax works, FYI](https://www.w3schools.com/cs/cs_inheritance.php).