# Type or namespace name could not be found for a DLL in the bin folder

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I have a third-party DLL. I have added this DLL to the bin folder of a Web Site project and can access it no problem.  I then added it to the bin folder of a Web Application project, and when trying to access it I receive "The type or namespace name could not be found."

From my research, it could be an issue with .NET target version. The Web Application project is targeting a higher version of .NET than the Web Site project so this should not be an issue.

I also checked that the file is present in the bin folder in the file system and has the same permissions as other files in the bin folder.

I have been searching for a solution for a while but most things that come up are for other project types like WPF, or talk about project references but this is a DLL.

Anything else I can check as to why the DLL cannot be used by the Web Application project? I am using Visual Studio 2017.

Comment: Copying DLLs into bin folders isn't the norm. For most project types, you add a *reference* to the DLL to the project, and the build system takes care of copying it into `bin` from *wherever* it normally resides. And also makes the *compiler* aware of it during compilation.

Comment: If you've manually copied the DLL to the bin folder it may not be properly referenced. Since you're using this on a web server it may be a directory permission issue or you nay need to use `Server.MapPath`.

Comment: I am 100% sure it's not a permissions issue as other DLL files in the bin folder are working and this one has same permissions (see question). I have added the file to the bin folder by right-clicking in VS - add existing file. Is this what you mean by manually copying? This is what I have been doing in my Web Site project for many years and never had an issue before. So, how in Web Application do I get it "properly referenced" when it is already in the bin folder?

Comment: Please provide a minimal reproducible example. Providing more information about the DLL may also be helpful.

Comment: [a .Net framework version incompatibility between two projects](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3304899/16764901) Does this help?

Comment: @JialeXue-MSFT Thanks for the link. No, that doesn't seem to be my issue, as I'm not using project references.

Answer (score 0):

[Managing references in a project](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/managing-references-in-a-project?view=vs-2019):

> Before you write code against an external component or connected service, your project must first contain a reference to it. A reference is essentially an entry in a project file that contains the information that Visual Studio needs to locate the component or the service.

> To add a reference, right click on the References or Dependencies node in Solution Explorer and choose Add Reference. You can also right-click on the project node and select Add > Reference. For more information, see [How to: Add or remove references](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-add-or-remove-references-by-using-the-reference-manager?view=vs-2019).

Web Site projects are an odd old beast which are different from every other project type. They're also [no longer recommended](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/dd547590(v=vs.110))

> For new development, we recommend that you choose web application projects. This topic explains that web site projects have some advantages, but many developers who choose web site projects eventually find that the disadvantages outweigh any perceived advantages. In addition, as new ASP.NET features are developed, they won’t always be made available for web site projects. For example, the next Visual Studio release after Visual Studio 2012 will have new tooling for creating web projects, and this new tooling will work only with web application projects.

I'd note that that page doesn't mention that, yes, Web Site projects add references just by copying into the bin folder.

Comment: Yeah, my Web Site project is probably about a decade old or so. I don't normally work with Web Application projects. Are you saying the DLL being in the bin folder doesn't matter? In that case why is there a bin folder? I did find the Add or Remove references link prior to posting, but nothing on that page mentions Web Site or Web Application projects. It seems to be for other project types like Windows Apps and I couldn't really follow the steps. Thanks though!

Comment: @user0474975 - in most project types, the `bin` folder is an *output* directory where the compiler places relevant binaries after the build is complete - and in such project types, they need a reference to know about the DLL *during* the build.

Comment: Oh okay, that helps. So, how in Web Application do I get it "properly referenced" when it is already in the bin folder?

Comment: @user0474975 - as it says in the first link/document, right click either the Project Node itself in Solution Explorer or the References/Dependenccies node under the Project Node and choose to Add Reference.

Comment: After a LOT of trial and error I finally got this working. The first link you sent didn't help me as mentioned. I didn't have the types of projects listed in the document and I couldn't follow the steps since I have Web Application and not Windows application. Maybe the terminology is just unfamiliar to me (and obvious to everyone else) as I am new to Web Applications. I am still not sure if I should have added the file to the bin folder or not since now I had to add it a different way also. Clear step-by-step instructions for Web App would be helpful, but anyway, got it working now so thanks!

Comment: @JialeXue-MSFT Since I am not exactly sure (I tried many things over a few days period) I can't really provide a complete answer to the question without more investigation. My one use case is working now. Maybe someone more familiar with Web Application projects could provide a more complete answer. Thanks!